# jq - Iterate over objects, add key to each item of array in value

Tags: json, jq

New to jq here.

I just want to ask how to add the key of an object to each item of its value and convert it to an array of objects instead. I have the following JSON format:

```
{
    "key1" : [
        "key1item1",
        "key1item2",
        "key1item3",
        "key1item4",
        ...
    ],
    "key2" : [
        "key2item1",
        "key2item2",
        ...
    ]
}
```

What I want to achieve is this:

```
{
    "key1" : [
        {
            'parent': 'key1',
            'key': 'key1_key1item1',
            'value': 'key1_item1',
        },
        {
            'parent': 'key1',
            'key': 'key1_key1item2',
            'value': 'key1_item2',
        }
        {
            'parent': 'key1',
            'key': 'key1_key1item3',
            'value': 'key1_item3',
        }
    ],
    "key2" : [
        {
            'parent': 'key2',
            'key': 'key2_key2item1',
            'value': 'key2_item1',
        },
        {
            'parent': 'key2',
            'key': 'key2_key2item2',
            'value': 'key2_item2',
        }
        {
            'parent': 'key2',
            'key': 'key2_key2item3',
            'value': 'key2_item3',
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
with_entries(
    .key as $key
    | .value |= map(
         {parent: $key,
          key: ($key + (tostring)), 
          value: .}) )
```